# Clifford algebra over non-Archimedean field

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, clifford-algebras

Usually the Clifford algebra is defined over the Reals $\mathbb{R}$ or the Complex  $\mathbb{C}$ numbers. Can the definition be extended over  non-Archimedean fields, such as the hyperreal numbers $\mathbb{R^*}$? I could not find reference on the question.

Comment: The Clifford algebra is defined for any quadratic module over a commutative ring. See any algebra book, e.g. Bourbaki, Algebra IX, §9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the Clifford algebra involves only first-order relations.  Therefore the transfer principle is applicable and the definition goes over to hyperreal fields which are elementary extensions of the real field.

Answer (score 3):

The Clifford algebra is defined for any quadratic module over a commutative ring. See any algebra book, e.g. Bourbaki, Algebra IX, §9.

Answer (score 0):

Also see section 2.5 of the paper:

*Ochsenius, Herminia; Olivos, Elena*, [**A comprehensive survey of non-Archimedean analysis in Banach spaces over fields with an infinite rank valuation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/596/11917), Shamseddine, Khodr (ed.), Advances in ultrametric analysis. Selected papers based on the presentations at the 12th international conference on $p$-adic functional analysis, Winnipeg, MB, Canada, July 2--6, 2012. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-9142-1/pbk; 978-1-4704-1024-7/ebook). Contemporary Mathematics 596, 215-236 (2013). [ZBL1321.32010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1321.32010).